# How to document project properties in gradle?

Tags: gradle

For example: if I have a gradle file which can accept and use a property named `DB`
that is used for testing against the named one.

`gradle test`  will run against some default

`gradle test -PDB=asd1` will run against a specific instance

but there is no easy way to show for the user that a specific property is handled

As a user I would expect it in the `gradle tasks` output

Should I define some task for example `advancedOptions` and list these things in that task's output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there's no good way to make properties self-documenting. It's a good question though. Would you mind posting this question as an idea on the [Gradle forum](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle)? This is certainly something that would be helpful to have in Gradle core. Currently, users will have to rely on the project's documentation.

Comment: link to gradle forum question:http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how-to-document-project-properties-in-gradle

Answer (score 2):

I should start by saying I came to gradle from ANT and my project is not Java based, so it is likely I'm not always doing things in a optimal gradle or groovy way...

That said, I also wanted to document the command line properties, and validate those entered along with values (if they only accepted a specific list of values). 
My approach is to have a map of possible command line properties to objects that contain a list of possible values, the first being the default value, and the rest the other accepted values so properties set on the command line can be validated.
This object also has a description field which I use to document the property, much like the task description field.
In addition to making the setting of command line property defaults automatic, this allows me to validate the command line properties, and display this information along with key task descriptions in a custom "describe" task (as help is reserved)

Here is some example code, this sets up the command line property information and runs when the build starts to validate the command line properties (for brevity, I don't have the value checking shown here):

```
task setCommandLineDefaults () {
    description 'set defaults for missing command line properties, and defines the possible values for each'
    project.ext.cmdLineDefaults = [
        _platform: new CmdLineInfo(values:["ios", "googleplay", "kyowon", "k_ios", "fuhu", "air", "awe"], description: "k_ios is for kyowon on ios - we may want to use this prop for just the OS target and have the partnerID separate down the road...")
        , _debug: new CmdLineInfo(values:["true", "false"], description:"if true, sets compiler-directives so that debug code (e.g., logging) can be excluded from the compiled code")
        , _showStats: new CmdLineInfo(values:["true", "false"], description: "if not set on the command line, the setting of _debug is used for the default")
        , _connect: new CmdLineInfo(values:["false", "true"], description: "only is relevant for DEBUG true, looks for an IP debug connection on startup if true")
        , _buildType: new CmdLineInfo(values:["dev", "adhoc", "release"], description: "(adhoc is ios only)")
        , _buildLevel: new CmdLineInfo(values:["", "alpha", "beta", "release"], description: "default is value in version.properties")
        ...
    ]
    // create the 'documentation' text for the properties
    project.ext.cmdLineInfo = "Command line info: this list comprises the only command line settings allowed, the first item in values is the default, if more than one, then those are the only valid values"
    cmdLineDefaults.each() { prop, value ->
        cmdLineInfo += "\n$prop: $value"
    }
    // verify that any command line properties set are expected
    def cmdLineProps = cmdLineDefaults.keySet() as String[]
    String errStr = ""
    def alts
    gradle.startParameter.projectProperties.each() { prop, value ->
        def values = cmdLineDefaults[prop]?.values
        if (!values) {
            alts = getClosestStrings(cmdLineProps, prop, 3) // this uses fuzzy string comparison to get at most 3 of the properites the user might have intended
            errStr += "Command line property '${prop}' not known, did you mean one of these? $alts \n"
        }
    }
    if (errStr) {
        throw new InvalidUserDataException("$errStr ${cmdLineInfo}")
    }
}
```

So a command line like

```
gradle compile -P_platfrm=ios
```

would return an error like:

```
Command line property '_platfrm' not known, did you mean one of these? [_platform]
```

Then I also have the describe task that uses the property info set above as well as task descriptions:

```
task describe() {}
describe << {
    // tasks to leave out of description list (as I mentioned, my project is not Java, so a lot of built in stuff is not relevant)
    def excludeTasks = ["buildDependents","buildNeeded","check","checkForFatalErrors","classes","compileJava","compileTestJava","jar","javadoc","processResources","processTestResources","test","testClasses"]
    project.tasks.each {
        if (it.description && !excludeTasks.contains(it.name)) {
            println "task ${it.name}: ${it.description}"
        }
    }
    println "\n${cmdLineInfo}"
}
```

I like this better than just the "tasks" task because there is a lot of repetition and irrelevant information in there for my project, and this also adds the property descriptions.
Hope this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that You can make use of task [rules](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10FD6) (but I'm not sure how it works with `gradle tasks)` or prepare a list if possible testing environments and create a task for every position.

Pseudo code:

```
def envs = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3']

envs.each { e ->
   projects.task(e) << {
       //TODO
   }
}
```

Second idea will print the list of all tasks.

Comment: i've tried this method too, but i ended up having 3-4 arguments for each task, sometimes not closely connected params; depenendency in this case can be done, but that's another pain

Comment: Could You please prepare and good example with expected input and output?

Comment: adding separate tasks for each possible variation will generate a massive task list, which will be meaningless (and would cause huge overhead during maintenace); i can't really give an example, because this is an open question...i appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You could "document" that in the task description.

```
task test {
    description = "Does stuff against thing declared by property 'db'. Ex: gradle test -Ddb=foo'
}
```

This would then be shown next to the task name when running `gradle tasks`.

Another way to pass an argument to a task via the CLI would be to use Gradle's `@Option` annotation, but this is an internal API that may change.

Comment: tasks descriptions are nice; but for cross cutting properties for example a property which can change the behaviour of all test tasks, i will take a look at @Option

Comment: Documenting properties that have global behavior is a bit more tricky. Things like that I would consider placing in a `gradle.properties` file so that you could comment them.

Comment: these properties have all have viable defaults; gradle.properties is on VCS; properties are handled by plugins, i don't want to update all modules properties files because i added a new property which is handled